# Gathering data from multiple streams in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I need to gather parsed XML data from multiple streams.

I get a list of files from a path and create multiple streams to parse XML data.  The data I need is aggregated in a JSONStream.

Is there a better way to do it in Node.js:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
let XmlStream = require('xml-stream');

async function getJsonStream(path) {

  let fileNames = await getFileNames(path);

  let jsonStream = JSONStream.stringify();

  for(let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileNames[i]);
    let xmlStream = new XmlStream(fileStream);

    xmlStream.on('endElement: Item', function(el) {
      jsonStream.write(el);
    });

    xmlStream.on('end', function() {
      if (i === fileNames.length - 1) {
        jsonStream.end();
      }
    });
  }

  return jsonStream;
}
```